# Javascript syntax , constants and logical-operators

Tags: javascript, syntax, constants, logical-operators

I was hoping someone could explain to me what this assignment operation does or point me in the right direction.

var CON = CON || {};

Thank you, 
Aleks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `||` (double pipe) means `OR`. So what this code does is:

If CON is [`truthy`](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) then it should be assigned to CON, else it should get an `{}` (empty object) as it's value.

It basically checks if the var CON is set, if not then it assigns {}. You find this short-hand code a lot in functions when you're not sure if all arguments are passed. Not sure why you would use it with constants, but I would have to see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used to prevent overwriting an object

Comment: This should be a comment